# Show adjacent div when hovering <a> element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to hide/show a `<ul>` that is outside of the parent element of the `<a>` that will be hovered.

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.shows:hover + .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="shows">SEASON</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">SHOWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

The adjacent selector doesn't seem to work and I can't seem to make anything else work. Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS third-party ***axe*** library for this.

Here are two examples:

## Select Next Sibling of Ancestor Element:

**Using `^` (select ancestor) and `+` (select next sibling)**

```css
.dropdown {
display: none;
}

.shows:hover ^ .navmenu + .dropdown {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="shows">SEASON</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">SHOWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

## Select Remote Element:

**Using `\` (select remote element)**

```css
.dropdown {
display: none;
}

.shows:hover \ .dropdown {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="shows">SEASON</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">SHOWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

---

**Further Reading on *axe* Selectors:**

http://www.rounin.co.uk/projects/axe/axe2.html

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`, and the `.shows` and `.dropdown` are not children of the same parent, and not adjacent. You'll have to move the `.dropdown` element to the same `<li>` in which `.shows` reside.

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.shows:hover+.dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="shows">SEASON</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">SHOWS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: or OP could use `js` to handle events, which he might when there are complex requirements :)

Comment: using jQuery or Js would be best! or else this will not work

Comment: You have many ways to do this. One of them is use CSS. In the working example that I've add, you can see that it's working with CSS. Click **Run code snippet**, and Hover **SEASON**.

Answer (score 0):

It would work **only** with sibbling elements that are **next** in the flow.

You could use a `<nav>` and plain `<a>` restyled as list items (`<li>`) to keep a coherent HTML5 structure that can also do the desired styling effect  :

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.shows:hover~.dropdown {
  display: block;
}
/* make those <a> look like <li>s resetting major default li rules */
.navmenu>a {
  display: list-item;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navmenu">
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
  <a href="#" class="shows">SEASON</a>
  <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">SHOWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

use `~` instead `+` since element to show is not right after but somwhere after.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!